# Clang on Mac using incorrect C++ version headers

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang

I am attempting to compile a program from the command line on Mac. I already have Xcode and the Xcode command line tools installed.

The problem is that the code in question requires a more current version of the vector class, so it is throwing errors during compilation. After digging into it, I have discovered that the first entry in the default include path is to what looks like a much older version of C++ headers. Searches online indicate this is not normal. So how do I change it?

Here is a command I am running to see the include path:

```
clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.11.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 264.3.102 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.3.0 -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir / -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.11.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o - -x c++ -
clang -cc1 version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) default target x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
/usr/local/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.3.0/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
/usr/include
/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

Notice that the first entry is  to .../usr/include/c++/**v1**

But elsewhere on my system, I have /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1.

The question is, how can I get it to use 4.2.1 headers instead of v1?

Comment: The 4.2.1 stuff is more than 9 years old, I doubt it will make you happier than the headers that come with clang. If you are comparing the the 1 from v1 with the 4 from 4.2.1: Those numbers are unrelated.

Comment: To solve your underlying problem, please [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] including the compilation options you used.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too sure how the v1 compares to the 4.2.1. But looking at the vector header file in each directory, I can see that the one in 4.2.1 will solve my issues. (If only I could include it)

Comment: The command in the question seems to be the most minimal example I can put together. I execute "clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null" and it shows the first include path is to c++/v1. Other examples of this I have seen online show the 4.2.1 headers as first. So there has to be a way to change it.

Comment: If you insist: `-isystem dir`  where `dir` is the include directory you want to add does what you (think you) need.

Comment: Yes, the -isystem command does seem to be able to insert directories at the top of the list. I feel like this is just working around the real problem though. I think something must be configured wrong on my machine to make it prefer v1and ignore 4.2.1.

Comment: There is no way using libstd++ 4.2.1 as the default on a normal computer is desirable in 2016. Only reason to still use this is if you are on some ancient server- / cluster-like system one cannot update.

Comment: Oh. So are you saying the headers in v1 are actually newer than the ones in 4.2.1?

Comment: I'm not an Apple user, I am not sure what exactly lives in this v1 directory, but libstdc++ 4.2 is certainly not the way to go. It's ancient. Either use the libc++ that comes with clang (`-stdlib=libc++`, might be redundant on Apple, dunno) or get a recent version of libstdc++ (most current one is 6.1.1) and use that. Both are good and modern implementations of the standard library. I believe 4.2 is still included because it was the last version with a license that allowed that, but yeah, it's legacy.